# Hyperledger Fabric 2 peers of same organisation causing issue with chaincode and couchdb

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am facing a very strange issue with `Hyperledger Fabric` `node.js sdk` issue.

Right now, my network consists of:

a.) Single org
b.) 2 peers of that org (peer0 and peer1).
c.) 1 orderer
d.) 1 ca

When using node.js sdk, both peers joined the channel as you can see in the code snippet below:

```
var fabric_client = new Fabric_Client();
var channel = fabric_client.newChannel(channelName);
var peer = fabric_client.newPeer('grpc://localhost:7051');
var peer2 = fabric_client.newPeer('grpc://localhost:8051');
channel.addPeer(peer);
channel.addPeer(peer2);
var order = fabric_client.newOrderer('grpc://localhost:7050')
channel.addOrderer(order);
```

I am calling a chaincode function written in `golang` that generates a unique id, create the hash of it (SHA256) and saves in `couchdb` and logs that hash to container like this:

```
"password":"5ef32e670c38727ce5011dad62ff1a150362433789fdd878f2623a08bbdc990b"
```

The issue is, when node.js sdk is configured with single peer.  It saves the same hash in `couchdb` that log shows. But when configured with 2 peers as the above sdk code snippet shows. The logged hash and couchdb hash does not match.

I think the hash changes because 2nd peer execute the same code again in which a random string is generated and hashed.

Any help/comment would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A few things:

1) Not sure what your endorsement policy is, but assuming it is the default then generally speaking you only need to request endorsement from a single peer in the organization

2) **Most importantly** you should not use non-deterministic functions within your chaincode.  If you actually had multiple organizations and the endorsement policy required signatures from multiple orgs, then your transaction would fail anyway (as peers from different orgs would generate different responses due to the non-deterministic unique id function you are using).  In this case, since you only require a single endorsement, the state would likely be updated but it would use the value of the first response.

Comment: This is the single organization with 2 peer and endosrment policy is given as below `peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.store.com:7050 -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n asset -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":[""]}' -P "AND ('storeMSP.peer')"` @Gari singh

Comment: As @gari-singh mentioned, something / some variable in the chaincode is non-deterministic (changes with peer to peer). SHA256 gives deterministic output for same input, see for the input (which may be changing peer to peer) that you are passing to the hashing function. If you put the source code in the question, problem will be more clear.

Comment: @JastiSriRadheShyam @Gari , Yes a variable is not deterministic in chaincode. That variable is for unique id generation as stub.PutState("unique-key", value) requires unique key. So that variable named `password` has new value everytime it executed (because we need to generate a random password when user register). Same case is happening with me, If I declare only a single peer in nodejs sdk, it works fine. But If I declare 2 peers than the value of that variable changes. Can you please tell me why this is happening? Is there any fix for that?

Comment: @DebutInfotech see the couchDB of both peers, one of them matchs the hash with the log. How are you getting the log of the chaincode response ? 
**Fix**: Don't generate the hash in chaincode, instead generate the hash in the NodeSDK, then pass the hash to the chaincode as arguments. If you want the hash not to be stored in transaction in arguments field then pass as transient arguments.
thanks.